# Python: When I try to run a code with (line +=) it gives a Typeerror

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I am fairly new to python so mostly everything I've tried so far has failed.

Whenever I run this snip of my code to try to make a single string from a sequence,

```
with open('C:/Users/Arda Turan/Desktop/sequence.txt') as file:
lines = []
for line in file:
    line+=(line.rstrip().split(","))
```

It gives the following error:

```
"C:\Users\Arda Turan\PycharmProjects\Untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/Arda Turan/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Arda Turan/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", 
line 4, in <module>
line+=(line.rstrip().split(","))
TypeError: must be str, not list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes: your `lines` is an array, try with `lines.append(<your string>)`

Comment: please, add your file sample and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you meant:

```
for line in file:
    lines.append(line.rstrip().split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes: your lines is an array, try with lines.append()

you're now using "lines" as if it is a string, while you have to use it as array, so use `lines.append()` instead of `+=`

if you want to do a "longer" string, change the declaration of lines with `lines = ''` and use the string catenation `+=` so you'll have a longer string instead of an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to append an element into the list. Try the following:

```
lines = []
with open('C:/Users/Arda Turan/Desktop/sequence.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line.rstrip().split(","))
```